How to assign different ipv6 for each domain in nginx?
I have a KVM VPS running Ubuntu 22.04 and using nginx as the webserver. I have a IPv6 /64 block so I added the extra IPs in the control panel. I also already added AAAA records on my DNS server. I want to assign a different ip for each domain so I uploaded a php file to find out what ipv6 my server shows to public but it's displaying the wrong ip address it's using whatever the last ipv6 created. This is my nginx config:
server {

    listen [79de:d3e4:211c:3963:e2d5:4b9d:00b8:2c60]:80;

    server_name sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/sub.domain.com.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sub.domain.com.error.log;


    root /var/www/sub.domain.com/htdocs;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    include common/php81.conf;
    
    include common/locations-wo.conf;
    include /var/www/sub.domain.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;

}

php:
<?php
      // create a new cURL resource
      $ch = curl_init ();

      // set URL and other appropriate options
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ipecho.net/plain");
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

      // grab URL and pass it to the browser

      $ip = curl_exec ($ch);
      echo "The public ip for this server is: $ip";
      // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
      curl_close ($ch);
    ?>

How can make each IP independent so IP 1 outgoing IP display as IP 1, IP 2 as IP 2, IP 3 as IP 3 etc...

Your PHP script does not determine the incoming IP address, it determines the IP address for outgoing connections.
Not tested, but you should be able to forward the variable $server_addr to php_fpm via the fastcgi_param directive.
Nginx:
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR $server_addr

PHP:
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR '];


What should work is using the add_header directive and checking the response header on your client.
add_header X-Server-Addr $server_addr

No server side scripting necessary here.
